# Can the "kubernetes" service be moved from the "default" namespace to the "kube-system" namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

The `kubernetes` service is in the `default` namespace. I want to move it to `kube-system` namespace. So I did it as follow:

```yaml
kubectl get svc kubernetes -o yaml > temp.yaml
```

This generates `temp.yaml` using current `kubernetes` service information. Then I changed the value of namespace to `kube-system` in `temp.yaml`. Lastly, I ran the following command:

```sh
kubectl replace -f temp.yaml
```

But I got the error:

```
Error from server: error when replacing "temp.yaml": service "kubernetes" not found
```

I think there is no service named `kubernetes` in the `kube-system` namespace.

Who can tell me how can to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Name and namespace are immutable on objects. When you try to change the namespace, `replace` looks for the service in the new namespace in order to overwrite it. You should be able to do `create -f ...` to create the service in the new namespace

Comment: Also, the `kubernetes` service is special… you may not be able to relocate it

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But the kubernetes service  is generated from the election in all nodes  in my test environment. I think there is different from normal.

Answer (score 3):

The `kubernetes` service is special and exists in the `default` namespace.  Too may things assume that to change it safely.